# countdown timer in viewpager not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer, android-viewpager

I have created a simple viewpager and fragment that creates a couple of textviews and a countdown timer, per view. Here is my adapter for the viewpager.

I call a function (populateView) with my index in the pager and based on that I populate the contents.

The problem I am running into is that, when my cmpDetails has say 3 views, and each with their own timer, clicking the timer in the first view randomly sets off timer in some other view...so if I swipe right to other positions, I see the timer counting down even though I did not click on THAT specific timer. So for example, View 1 timer starts view 3 timer.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing, please? Thanks

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cmpDetails;
    TextView timer;
    TextView nextName;
    TextView eName;
    TextView cmpTitle;
    CountDownTimer ct;
    boolean coutndownIsRunning = false;
    private ViewGroup groupLayout;


        private Context mContext;
        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cmpDetails) {
    this.cmpDetails=cmpDetails;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmp_child_item, collection, false);

    cmpTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cmp_title);
    eName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ename);
    nextName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.next);
    timer = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.timer);

    textView6 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    textView7 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    secs = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.secs);

    if (ct != null)  {
        ct.cancel();
    }

    groupLayout = layout;
    PopulateView(position);
    collection.addView(layout);

    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
    if (ct != null)  {
        ct.cancel();
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cmpDetails.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return cmpDetails.get(position).get("name");
}

public void PopulateView(final int index) {
    timer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ct != null && coutndownIsRunning)  {
                ct.cancel();
            }
            ct = new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(cmpDetails.get(index).get("time"))*1000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    coutndownIsRunning = true;
                    timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    coutndownIsRunning = false;
                    timer.setOnClickListener(null);
                    ct.cancel();
                    timer.setText("Done!");
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cmpDetails.get(index).get("time")) > 0) {
                    }
                }
            };
            ct.start();
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using a single instance of `Timer` for all views. Try to use different instances, for each view separately. In total 3 instances. Than you'll have 1 timer for each view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Right. I fixed that and had to make the TextView instance not global either. Once I moved the TextView instance down to PopulateView it started working perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: But now the problem is, I want only one timer to run at a time. If timer 1 is running, and user clicks timers 2 or 3 timer timer 1 should stop. I had one timer instance to get that done. But with this I can't get that done. Any ideas?

Comment: When i say you need to use different instances, i mean that you need to create different new objects of class `Timer`. Basically you need to start the timer separately for each view. Then when you press stop, on the second view, only the second time will stop.

Comment: Oh I must have misunderstood....any chance you could please post a quick code sample, I'm not entirely positive I understand "i mean that you need to create different new objects of class Timer. Basically you need to start the timer separately for each view". Thanks so much

Comment: When you start a timer basically you create a new object of class `Timer`. I assume you are using something like this: `Timer T=new Timer();` If you are using a `CountDownTimer` i assume you are using somethig like this: `new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {...}.start();` So all you need to do is to create 3 instances, one for each view. Obviously you need to have 3 different views. one for each timer.

Comment: Right. Problem is, the # views are downloaded from the network and are dynamically produced by a server. It's not always 3, it could be 10 it could be 20 it could be 5.

Comment: There's not a problem, as long as are different views. The most important thing is to start the Timer three times on different objects.